# WPF Button Styling with OuterGlowBitmapEffect

Tags: wpf, button, styles, mouseover

I have managed to style a button such that there is a the background I wanted (Normal). However, I want to create an OuterGlowBitmapEffect on the content. Also, when I modify the style, it reverts to the default for MouseOver, Pressed, and HasFocus.

Here is the image of what I want, how could you do this using WPF Styles

http://tinypic.com/r/2s9ybfs/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code I can't say for sure, but you need to add the "OuterGlowBitmapEffect" to the `MouseOver`, `Pressed` and `HasFocus` styles as well.

All these states come as a package and need to be modified in concert.

If you can, get hold of Expression Blend. This has options for creating templates and styles from existing ones and then for modifying the individual components of each aspect of the style.